# Lagged Dependent variable in OLS

Tags: time-series, least-squares, lags, dynamic-regression

I have a question about one of my models. I am sorry if I am using Terms wrongly, as I am part of the management research field and this quite often leads to different terminologies.

I try to model an OLS Regression, in which I predict an Outcome in the future (t+1) based on predictors in the present. Therefore my model simply is:

(1): Y(t) = α1Y(t−1) + β0X0(t-1) + β1X1(t-1) + β2X2(t-1) ... + εt

but after doing some Research I did not find any models like this. When digging into (time-)lagged dependent variable papers, the model under investigation is always specified as:

(2): Y(t) = α1Y(t−1) + β0X0(t) + β1X1(t) + β2X2(t) ... + εt

Therefore, I was wondering why this occurs. In management Research some Analysis try to investigate the effect of predictors in (t) on a lagged outcome (t+1) to overcome single-source bias, but quite often they do not control for the potential Dynamics, so I wanted to investigate my issue more properly. Unforturnately, after realizing that (2) is the typical model discussed in economics, I am not sure whether it even makes sense to test a model as in (1) in General? Does the same recommendations hold in (1) as in (2) like OLS Regression is a strongly biased prediction, especially with autocorrelated errors or can I simply specify the model in OLS as stated in (1)?

Additional Information:
In my model the dependent variable is perceived health (which theoretically makes sense to be dependent on your perceived health in the past). The time-lag of the data is approx 1 year. I have Survey data with timepoints (T)=2 and Observations each N(t)= 6000 with 30% overlap of participants of T1 and T2. The idea was to do multiple (chain) imputations for missings in t1 (highest missing value in predictors 30%) and potentially also imputing the missing data on the outcome variable in t+1 which seems to be allowed when having a strong predictor in time period before t (same question: health Status: correlation health Status t and t+1 approx: 0.66)

If it happens, I am sorry for causing confusion, but I would be very grateful for any advice!

Dear John